# exit a while loop , cin . using ctrl-Z/ctrl-D not working c++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, exit, eof

i have a while loop and code below

```
string namn, word;

while(getline(cin, namn)){
    istringstream iss(namn);
    vector<string> v;
    while(iss >> word ){
        v.push_back(word);
    }
    for(auto elements: v){
        cout << elements << endl;
    }
}
cout << "do something" <<endl;
```

When I run the code the loop works fine but I can not quit the loop using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> (in windows).

I have also tried this below:

```
int main(){
  string namn;
  string pris;
  string antal;
  vector<string> v;
  while(cin >> namn >> pris >> antal){
    v.push_back(namn);
    v.push_back(pris);
    v.push_back(antal);
  }
  // do something with the vector maybe print it
  // i can not exit the loop and continue here
  return 0;
 }
```

I have also tried this third solution but it is not working either:

```
int main(){
  string name;
  vector<string> v;

  while(!cin.eof()&& cin.good()){
     cin >> name;
     v.push_back(name);
  }
  // after exiting the loop with ctrl-Z (in windows, ctrl-d in linux)
  // do something with the vector, but it never goes here
}
```

The task that I am doing or is going to solve is you have multiple input on a line for example name, price, amount. Then I am going to store those items in a vector. The exit should be with using of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> not typing quit or something else.

Comment: Did you hit enter key after ctrl-z? Try adding a break if namn.empty() to exit the loop with an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own question. The problem was that I was using `istringstream` before and switched it out to `stringstream` instead, now quitting with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> works.

```
Firstclass myclass;
string item, data;
vector<string> split_input;

// reads in on line of string until ctrl-z/ctrl-d
while(getline(cin, data)){
    stringstream str_stream(data);
    // reading the values separate adding them to vector
    while(str_stream >> item{
        split_input.push_back(item);
    }
    // if amount is not given
    if(v.size() == 2){
        myclass.insert_data(split_input[0], stod(split_input[1]), 1.00);
    }
    // if if amount is given
    else{
        myclass.insert_data(split_input[0], stod(split_input[1]),   stod(split_input[2]));
    }
    // clearing the vector
    split_input.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `std::basic_ios::operator bool()` returns whether the stream has not failed, and it is not the same as `!eof()`. You probably have to change your condition into `while(cin >> namn >> pris >> antal && !cin.eof())`.

Comment: hmm, i tried that expression without luck , any more suggestions?